# Cannot left-click go to an anchor tag's link

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, anchor

I have the following setup, for an extension for Google Chrome browser. Everything works fine except one thing. First, I click on the extension button. When I left-click on the "here" in "Click here!", nothing happens. When I right click on "here" and choose "Open link in new tab", a new tab does open, pointing to https://www.yahoo.com. Why doesn't left-click work?

A javascript file is calling the below line so that a popup is shown from an extension button:

```
chrome.browserAction.setPopup({'tabId', tabId, 'popup': 'page1.html'});
```

page1.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head/>
  <body>
    <iframe src="page2.html"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

page2.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head/>
  <body>
    Click <a href="https://www.yahoo.com">here</a>!
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to open the link in a new tab, add `target="_blank"` to the `<a>` tag. This will cause a new tab to be opened with the contents of the link.

Your code should be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head/>
  <body>
    Click <a href="https://www.yahoo.com" target="_blank">here</a>!
  </body>
</html>
```